# PHP Not Displaying Fatal Error

Tags: php

I know there's loads of question re: PHP not displaying errors but I can't seem to find anything that fits my issue. I have a page that I know overloads the memory and in the logs I get the following message:

```
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79 bytes)
```

However no error is displayed on the screen - it is just blank.

In my php.ini I have the following settings:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

I have also tried adding the following to the top of the script in question

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

NB. Other errors do display correctly - it's just this memory error that appears to produce a blank screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: Use `error_reporting(1);` or `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at top of the .php file

Comment: @KalaiM, thanks but I've tried that two and still get a blank screen.

Comment: have  a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: @ChetanAmeta, Yeah, i;ve seen that Q and have the relevant settings in php.ini but just receive a blank screen. Other errors do show but this memory error just shows a blank screen